# bebo integration into iphone application

Tags: iphone, social-networking

Hi. I am developing one application for iPhone. In which I have integrated twitter, facebook, Myspace. Using my app I can update status and image. In the same way I want to integrate Bebo social networking site.

I find Bebo's developer site http://developer.bebo.com/ here. But I did not found any API related to Objective C or iPhone related stuff. How can I do this integration?

Comment: Please don't put "Provide me any useful resource asap" (or "urgent" etc.) into questions, it's considered rude and is not likely to get you help any more quickly. People here are helping out for nothing and you have no right to make demands on their time or at what time they help you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's an existing API for bebo access on iPhone.

You'll have to think about rolling your own. The site you posted a link to seems to have useful info. Or there's some (hard on the eye) info here:

http://www.bebo.com/Profile.jsp?MemberId=6945769847

Comment: there is no useful things i found.